# LAS Dataset to Raster tool not allowing resolution of window size in Triangulation interpolation to be manually chosen using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, resolution, las, cell-size

I'm working on a workflow to convert a LAS file into a raster to calculate a bare earth model for drone surveys (~300m x 300m with a point density of ~1.5pt/cm^2) using the LAS Dataset to Raster tool.

I originally had it working in ArcMap 10.6, but recently had to change to ArcGIS Pro 2.6, and now the model window size parameter won't cooperate. I'm using Triangulation with a minimum point selection at a window size of 2m to account for variation in the ground surface and then export to a 0.02m cell size raster based on my point density, but when I try to change the Resolution of the window size, it automatically switches the resolution back to 5m. Just wondering how I can make it use a smaller window size (2m) instead of the default (5m)?

Answer (score 0):

I recently used [LAS  Tools](https://rapidlasso.com). It is limited by several parameters because it is shareware. I finished using [PDAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696903/create-geotiff-from-lidar-file). Maybe that suits your needs for accomplishing LAS to DEM raster.